# Printer printing blank page between copies when using lp -n 2

Tags: cups, lp

Would anyone know why printer prints blank page between copies when running following?

```
$ lp -d Brother_HL_L2370DW_series -n 2 -o fit-to-page -o MediaType=stationery-heavyweight -o Quality=High -o PageSize=Custom.4x6in file.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using `-o Duplex=None`

Comment: Posted here on behalf of @SBN : can you please explain how you solved this problem with -o Duplex=None